# Plotting .gv/.dot file avoiding using graphviz

Tags: python, graph

I'd like to ask you if there's a method, using Python, that allows to convert a premade .gv/.dot file into a png/svg file. I've tried pydot but since I can't install graphviz the write_* function doesn't work. Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't say why you can't install Graphviz.  Try using a web-based version of Graphviz.

Comment: Hello sroush, thank you for your comment. I just can't install external software

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.